# How to use a column's value in array index in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas, subset

I want to subset a dataset based on the value of a column from a set of columns.

For ex,
I want to subset the dataset by `age`>50 but i have 10 age columns ranging from `age1`-`age10`. Also, there is another column named `identifier` (with values from 1-10) which tells me based on what column should i subset the value.

Let's say my `identifier` column value is 5, I should check whether the value in column `age5` is greater than 50 or not.

This is what I tried, But it's not working.

```
data library.table2;
    set library.table1;
    array age[10] age1 -- age10;
    if( age(identifier)>50 );
    RUN;
```

Comment: Explain how it is not working.  Are you getting errors in the log?  Why are you using a positional variable list?  Perhaps you mean to use simple ennumerated variable list instead `age1 - age10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of variables meant by a positional variables list like `age1 -- age10` could be completely different than the variable list meant by a simple enumerated list like `age1 - age10`.  The former looks for all variables **BY POSITION** between AGE1 and AGE10.  It could include 2 variables or 200 variables. It might include some character variables.

If you want AGE1,AGE2,...,AGE10 then you can either list the variables or specify the dimension.  If you do not list the actual variable names in some way then it will just append an index number to the name of the array to generate the variable names for the array.

```
array age age1-age10;
array age[10] ;
```

If you are a belt and suspenders type of person you can specify both the dimension and the specific variable names.

```
array age[10] age1-age10;
```

You might also want to check that IDENTIFIER is a valid index.

```
if identifier in (1:10) then if not age(identifier)>50 then delete;
```